# my application freezes whenever i tap button

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, freeze, login-page

i am creating a signup/login page for my android application. here is my code. i have used shared preferences. the code doesn't have errors. but still whenever i run it in eclipse, it freezes whenever i click on signup button and an error occur "confirm perspective switch"

```
enter code here

MainActivity.java
package com.example.login;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText pass;
Button login,signup;
SharedPreferences sharedpreference;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

     login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            sharedpreference= getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE); 
            String restoredText = sharedpreference.getString("Name", "password");
            if(pass.getText().toString().equals(restoredText)){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, JournalActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INVALID PASSWORD",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
     signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent sign= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(sign);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

SignupActivity.java

```
package com.example.login;

public class SignupActivity extends Activity
{

        EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword;
        Button btnCreateAccount;
        SharedPreferences pref;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);


                editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
                editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);    
                btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);


                btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                        // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                        if(password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                        }
                        // check if both password matches
                        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Does Not Matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                             pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",  MODE_PRIVATE); 
                            Editor editor= pref.edit();
                            editor.putString("Name", password);
                            editor.apply();

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent i= new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                        }


                    }
                });
        }




        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

}
```

Comment: please post your logcat output

Comment: 11-25 17:47:30.694: W/Trace(388): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

logcat

Comment: @Actiwitty problem is solved. i don't know how.but the moment i exit eclipse, my app starts working again in emulator